# Change column based on matched cases in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
data=data.frame(time=c(1,1,0.5,1), columnB= c(1,2,5,6), columnC= c(1,2,2,5))
```

```
time  columnB  columnC  
1.0        1         1
1.0        2         2
0.5        5         2
1.0        6         5
```

I would like to modify "time" based on the elements of column B and column C such as
when the element of column B appears for the first time in column C then "time" takes
the value of 5 in column B.

I hope it's not confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
time  columnB  columnC  
1.0        1         1
1.0        2         2
0.5        5         2
0.5        6         5
```

Comment: I for one not understand the question nor the example result, if the second table is an example result.

Comment: .. also are Column `A` and Column `time` the same thing?

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard and Edo for your kind comments. They helped me to edit my question in a better way. I think Allan got it right and it works for me

Comment: "_... based on the elements of column B and column C such as when the element of column B appears for the first time in column C ..._" but what then about row one and two? `columnB` is matched for the first time by `columnC` in both cases. However, the `time` values does not take the value of row three (the one with `columnB` being five) in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're asking for (it certainly gives the desired output):

```r
within(data, time[match(columnC, columnB) < match(columnC, columnC)] <- time[columnB == 5])
#>   time columnB columnC
#> 1  1.0       1       1
#> 2  1.0       2       2
#> 3  0.5       5       2
#> 4  0.5       6       5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>